# Total count is not added into existing List

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot with Rest API in java. I have try to get All Event List between startDate and endDate and order By startDate but from each date only 6 record get not more. if each date of record is > 6 then i want to add count into that particular date of record.

Suppose in this month date wise -n no. of event is there. But i want only six record every date not more record is require if more record is available then i want to add total count of that Date of record. In this eventsListTwoDates object i have got List of All Events.

I have got each date of 6 record from eventsListTwoDates list but count is not added if that each date of record is > 6.

1.JPA custom Query

```
  @Query("SELECT new com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Events(e.id, e.eventImg , e.multipleDays , e.startDate, e.endDate, e.startTime, e.endTime, e.eventStatus, e.paid, e.fee, e.passportTickets, e.location, e.city, e.myFavourite, e.remainingTickets, e.eventName, e.passport, e.typesOfEvents, e.eventPassportOptions, e.promoCode, e.subTitle, e.expectedAttendance)" +
            " from Events e WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY e.startDate")
    List<Events> findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDateTest(String startDate, String endDate);
```

2. Code

```
public GenericResponse getListEvent()
{
   List<Events> eventsListTwoDates = eventsDao.findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDateTest(firstMondayCurrentMonth, lastDateCurrentMonth);
   Events events = new Events();
   List<Events> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i=0; i<eventsListTwoDates.size(); i++){
       int count = 1;
       for (int j=i+1; j<eventsListTwoDates.size(); j++) {
          if (eventsListTwoDates.get(i).getStartDate().equals(eventsListTwoDates.get(j).getStartDate())){
              count++;
          }
       }
       if (count<=6) {
          events.setCount(count);
          eventsList.add(i,events);
          eventsList.add(eventsListTwoDates.get(i));
          System.out.println(count + " : " +eventsListTwoDates.get(i).getStartDate());
       }
   }
     return APIResponseBuilder.build(true, eventsList, commonMessages.findAllTrue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're never actually returning `count` at all so that might be why you don't have it available. Also, with date assessment, it's usual for me to forget to take into account the time portion, so some date functions aren't assessed properly and we get bugs like this one.

I would debug your code slowly just to be sure of what your function does. Also, don't you want to be looping through each date range, instead of the whole list twice? You can use the `Calendar`/`LocalDateTime` classes to get a count quite easily.

Comment: Here i have a using Date without time

Comment: is there a reason you're looping through the same list of events twice? I still can't see where you're adding `count` to the result. Don't you need to add `events.setCount(count);` to the list, if it is > 6?

Comment: yes because i have compare that list with same startDate field which is match then tahat count is increase for that Date

Comment: if it is >6 then i want to require to add count. it is inform to further API call\